# How to create coloured tables with Sweave and xtable?

Tags: r, reproducible-research

I am using Sweave and **xtable** to generate a report.

I would like to add some coloring on a table. But I have not managed to find any way to generate colored tables with xtable.

Is there any other option?

Comment: what is the coloured table? Cells with colour background? Cell text different colour? In the last scenario, the solution might be wrapping the values with appropriate tex commands.

Comment: I need the background of one row to be of a specific color. Do I have to rewrite an xtable function?

Comment: xtable has already been rewritten (or perhaps pre-written) as the [latex](http://lib.stat.cmu.edu/S/Harrell/help/Hmisc/html/latex.html) function in the R package Hmisc.  Personally I swear by it for proper looking tables.  I haven't checked whether it has room for the fancy insertion trick described below, though I'd be surprised if not.

Comment: @Conjugate You're right, although it is not as straightforward as I would have thought; I've updated my response with your suggestion.

Comment: @chl 'not straightforward' is an understatement.  That function is a beast, although a very capable one.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Although I didn't try this explicitly from with R (I usually post-process the Tables in Latex directly with `\rowcolor`, `\rowcolors`, or the [colortbl](http://ctan.org/pkg/colortbl) package), I think it would be easy to do this by playing with the `add.to.row` arguments in `print.xtable()`. It basically expect two components (passed as `list`): (1) row number, and (2) $\LaTeX$ command. Please note that command are added at the end of the specified row(s).

It seems to work, with the `colortbl` package. So, something like this

```
<<result=tex>>
library(xtable)
m <- matrix(sample(1:10,10), nr=2)
print(xtable(m), add.to.row=list(list(1),"\\rowcolor[gray]{.8} "))
@
```

gives me

[image]

(This is a customized Beamer template, but this should work with a standard document. With Beamer, you'll probably want to add the `table` option when loading the package.)

**Update:**

Following @Conjugate's suggestion, you can also rely on [Hmisc](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Hmisc/index.html) facilities for handling $\TeX$ output, see the many options of the `latex()` function. Here is an example of use:

```
library(Hmisc)
## print the second row in bold (including row label)
form.mat <- matrix(c(rep("", 5), rep("bfseries", 5)), nr=2, byrow=TRUE)
w1 <- latex(m, rownamesTexCmd=c("","bfseries"), cellTexCmds=form.mat, 
            numeric.dollar=FALSE, file='/tmp/out1.tex')
w1  # call latex on /tmp/out1.tex
## highlight the second row in gray (as above)
w2 <- latex(m, rownamesTexCmd=c("","rowcolor[gray]{.8}"), 
            numeric.dollar=FALSE, file='/tmp/out2.tex')
w2
```